# How many executors are assigned to listen to a kafka topic in Spark-kafka Integration in Spark 2.1?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark cluster with 17 executors in total. I have integrated Spark 2.1 with Kafka and reading the data from topic like:

```scala
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .options("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")
  .options("subscribe","test")
  .load
```

Now I want to know that when I'll Submit my spark application in cluster mode how many executors (out of the total 17) will be assigned to listen to a Kafka topic and creating micro-batches in Structured Streaming.

Also, how can I limit the size of a micro-batch in Structured Streaming when reading from Kafka?

Answer (score 2):

Structured Steaming uses a single partition per Kafka topic partition. Since a single partition is processed by a single core, it will use at most this number of executors, from the ones assigned to the application.

Number of messages processed in a batch depends primarily on the trigger used (and as a consequence batch interval, if batching is used at all) however take a look at [`maxOffsetsPerTrigger`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html):

> Rate limit on maximum number of offsets processed per trigger interval. The specified total number of offsets will be proportionally split across topicPartitions of different volume.